# Windows Server Users dialog box before logging in

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, login, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server

In my previous job, we had a dialog box open up when trying to log in into a windows server but the maximum logged in users was already reached. It shows each logged in user and whether they are active or inactive. And then you have the option to kick a user to get their spot or you can cancel logging in. What feature is this called? Or any reference or links to a documentation? My new job does not have this feature and the current logged in user will be automatically kicked out when someone else tries to log in. Thanks!

Comment: This relates to group policy, specifically around terminal services. Is the remote server on Windows 2012 R2 (hence the tag)?

Comment: The server in my new job is Windows 2012 R2. I forgot what our server was in my previous job. Thanks!

Comment: Have you contacted your IT department?